# INSERT INTO not working

Tags: php, sql

I have an annoying problem with my code, that refuses to insert into a MySQL table.
Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the SQL code..

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitpraes'])) 
{
    $praesTitel = $row['kontypeBeskriv'];           
    $praesStr = $_POST['praesidag'];
    $konID = $row['konID']; 

    $sql=("INSERT INTO  `mah1233411190550`.`praestationer` (
        `praesID` ,
        `praesTitel` ,
        `praesStr` ,
        `brugerID` ,
        `holdID`,
        `konID` 
        )
        VALUES (NULL ,  '$praesTitel',  '$praesStr',  '$brugerID', '$holdID', '$konID');");
    mysql_query($sql);
    echo $sql;
}
?>
```

And the php code...

```
<?php
$virksomhedsID = $_SESSION['virkID'];
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM konkurrence 
        INNER JOIN konkurrenceType ON konkurrenceType.kontypeID = konkurrence.kontypeID 
        WHERE konkurrence.virkID = '$virksomhedsID' 
        AND (CURDATE() BETWEEN `konStart` AND `konSlut`)";  

$result = mysql_query($sql);                
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  

echo '<td width="12%" height="45">';
echo 'konID' . $row['konID'];   
echo '<img src="' . $row['kontypeFilename'] . '" width="38px" alt="' . $row['kontypeBeskriv'] . '"/>';
echo '</td>';           
echo '<td width="25%">Jeg har i dag ' .  $row['kontypeBeskriv'] . 't</td>';
echo '<td>';

echo '<input class="textboxReport" type="text" name="praesidag" size="3"/>&nbsp;km &nbsp;&nbsp;';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submitpraes" id="submitpraes" value="GEM" />';
echo '</td>';
?>
```

The sql looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `mah1233411190550`.`praestationer` ( `praesID` , `praesTitel` , `praesStr` , `brugerID` , `holdID`, `konID` ) VALUES (NULL , '', '2', '39', '23', '');
```

And shows that the following is not working, but I cannot see why...

```
$praesTitel = $row['kontypeBeskriv'];           
$konID = $row['konID'];
```

Comment: (1) Do `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` (2) this screams for sql injection (3) mysql* functions will be deprecated soon; use mysqli or pdo (+ you wil get rid of point (2)).

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: can you put an echo mysql_error() after querying and tell us the error message ?

Comment: if you are using an input and submit this needs to be in <form> tags. use hidden inputs to carry over post values.

Comment: The error is this
    INSERT INTO mah1233411190550.praestationer ( praesID , praesTitel , praesStr , brugerID , holdID, konID ) VALUES (NULL , '', '2', '39', '23', '');
the sql doesn't get the praesTitel or konID..

I am using a Form
<form method="POST" action="" id="submitpraes">

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) as previously harassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form needs to be set up like this. with your needed values in it:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="" value="' . $row['konID'] . '">'; 
echo '<input type="hidden" name="" value="' . and $row['kontypeBeskriv'] . '">';        
echo '<input class="textboxReport" type="text" name="praesidag" size="3"/>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submitpraes" id="submitpraes" value="GEM" />';
echp '</form>';
```

Make the action point to where ever you need the form to post.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting your variables from the POST here:

```
$praesTitel = $row['kontypeBeskriv'];           
$praesStr   = $_POST['praesidag'];
$konID      = $row['konID'];
```

you should get your values from the `$_POST` and not `$row`.

```
$praesTitel = $_POST['kontypeBeskriv'];           
$praesStr   = $_POST['praesidag'];
$konID      = $_POST['konID'];
```

as there's no row to fetch in your first php code.

Comment: Thank your answering my question.

If I dont have a $_POST['kontypeBeskriv']; , how can I then get the data? As now the data comes from the $row

Im sorry but isn't _POST for data recieved from user via eg a form?

Comment: if you are using an input and submit this needs to be in <form> tags. use hidden inputs to carry over post values.

Comment: well you tell me where you get the `kontypeBeskriv` data if it doesn't come from the POST. I can't see any query in the begining of your first PHP?

Comment: kontypeBeskriv comes from the query 

SELECT * 
   FROM konkurrence 
   INNER JOIN konkurrenceType ON konkurrenceType.kontypeID = konkurrence.kontypeID 
   WHERE konkurrence.virkID = '$virksomhedsID' 
   AND (CURDATE() BETWEEN `konStart` AND `konSlut`)

Comment: So >Roy if I understand you correctly I need to write the kontypeBeskriv into a hidden field, and then get it as _POST
Correct?

Comment: yes, set up form and put all values that yo need but do not want seen in hidden inputs.

Comment: I have added
echo '<input type="hidden" name="date-submitted" value="' . $row['konID'] . '">';
and
echo '<input type="hidden" name="date-submitted" value="' . and $row['kontypeBeskriv'] . '">';
and added 
$praesTitel = $_POST['kontypeBeskriv'];   
$konID = $_POST['konID'];
But still the values doesn't come along
INSERT INTO `mah1233411190550`.`praestationer` ( `praesID` , `praesTitel` , `praesStr` , `brugerID` , `holdID`, `konID` ) VALUES (NULL , '', '999', '39', '23', '');

Comment: sorry! I need to change the names.. 2 sec

Comment: This is incorrect :
`<input type="hidden" name="date-submitted" value="' . $row['konID'] . '">` correct is `<input type="hidden" name="konID" value="' . $row['konID'] . '">` .. Same for other field

Comment: NOW ITS WORKING!!
Thank you so much gentlements, very nice. Thank you!

Comment: Please if you have the time, have a look at another very dificult problem at..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923599/a-difficult-many-to-many-relation-with-checkboxes
Thank you

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then check your HTML whether the inputs are there with correct values and names within the same form as `praesidag`

Comment: But if you have the time please help me with two things more..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923840/update-data-from-db-to-user-to-db

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923599/a-difficult-many-to-many-relation-with-checkboxes