# UPDATE data from db to user to db through an input field

Tags: php, sql-update

UPDATE data from db to user to db through an input field.
Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with this UPDATE.
I'm getting the data from a field where I'm also writing from db, is that not possible?

My sql code looks like this..

```
<?php session_start(); $brugerID = $_SESSION['brugerID']; $holdID = $_SESSION['holdID']; ?>
```

My php code looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="submitvaegt">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><h2>Hvor meget vejer du idag?</h2></td>
    </tr>
        <?php
        $brugerensID = $_SESSION['brugerID'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `brugere` 
        WHERE brugerID = '$brugerensID'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td rowspan="3" valign="middle" width="128">';
        echo '<img src="http://www.mahogni.com/afs/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/weight.png" width="60"></td>';
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        echo '<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="245" height="35">Jeg vejer i dag</td>'; //vaegtnu
        echo '<td width="280">';
        echo '<input class="textboxReport" type="text" name="vaegtnu" size="3" value="';
        if ($row['vaegtnu']==0) 
        { 
            echo $row['vaegtstart'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo $row['vaegtnu'];
        }           
        echo '"/>&nbsp;kg&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submitvaegt" id="submitvaegt" value="GEM" />';
        echo '<td width="280" height="35">Jeg har til nu tabt</td>'; //vaegtstart - vaegtnu
        echo '<td align="right">';
        if ($row['vaegtnu']==0) 
        { 
            echo $row['vaegtstart']-$row['vaegtstart'];
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo $row['vaegtstart']-$row['vaegtnu'];
        }           
        echo '&nbsp;kg</td>';               
        echo ' </tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td height="35">Mit mål er</td>'; //vaegtslut
        echo '<td>'. $row['vaegtslut'] . '&nbsp;kg</td>'; 
        echo '<td height="28">Jeg mangler at tabe</td>'; //vaegtslut - vaegtnu ELLER vaegtslut - vaegtstart
        echo '<td>';

        if ($row['vaegtnu']==0) 
        { 
            echo $row['vaegtslut']-$row['vaegtstart'] . '&nbsp;kg';
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo $row['vaegtslut']-$row['vaegtnu'] . '&nbsp;kg';
        }
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        ?>
</form>
```

Comment: what error did you get ? can you print the value of `$brugerensID` and check whether there's a matching value in your table ?

Comment: you see, first Im getting the vaegtnu(weightnow) from db and write it in a textbox, where also the user can write a new number, say if they have lost extra weight. The new number needs to be stored as the new veagtnu and send to db in the update, when the user press Gem (save), but the update doesn't work, is it because its not possible to do it like that or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: yes the $brugerensID (userID) is 39 its in the db, it comes from session

Comment: but does the UPDATE look correct?

Comment: For your first php code, is it your whole code ? because I don't see where you get your weight and user id values.. apart from that i don't see anything wrong

Comment: UPDATE is fine if you get the correct values and successfully connect to your DB

Comment: also, try this `mysql_query("UPDATE brugere SET vaegtnu='$vaegtnu' WHERE brugerID='$brugerensID'") or die('SQL Error !<br>'.mysql_error());?>` This way you can see any error you might have

Comment: I got this error:
SQL Error !
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: now try `echo "UPDATE brugere SET vaegtnu='$vaegtnu' WHERE brugerID='$brugerensID'";` and tell us what you see

Comment: I have put back the single quotes and now there is no error, but it does not update the users weight, as it's suppose to, in db it just says 0

Comment: if I change SET vaegtnu='70' WHERE brugerID='39' it writes to db!

Comment: when I insert 
echo "UPDATE brugere SET vaegtnu='$vaegtnu' WHERE brugerID='$brugerensID'"; it just writes that on top of screen

Comment: well it is supposed to write the query with the actual values.. what exactly does it output? Does it replace your variables with their values ?

Comment: no, how can i echo it out? like echo $sql;

Comment: here's how:  `echo "UPDATE brugere SET vaegtnu='$vaegtnu' WHERE brugerID='$brugerensID'";`

Comment: but I've tried that, its just writes exactly the same..

Comment: i get: UPDATE brugere SET vaegtnu='' WHERE brugerID=''

Comment: how can i show you all of the code?

Comment: that's odd.. because it should replace the variables with the values.. can you edit your post and put where you get your two variables ?

Comment: do I need a if (isset($_POST['submitvaegt'])) ??

Comment: i was more interested in the first part :)

Comment: as I suspected, your variables are not set.. so I need to see the code where you set them `$vaegtnu=?` and `$brugerensID=?`

Comment: its difficult to use this site, when posting code, it doesn't accept the code as code..

Comment: but you can see that comes from session and also I have it <?php
   $brugerensID = $_SESSION['brugerID'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `brugere` 
   WHERE brugerID = '$brugerensID'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: and vaegtnu comes from the input textbox echo '<input class="textboxReport" type="text" name="vaegtnu" size="3" value="';
   if ($row['vaegtnu']==0) 
   { 
    echo $row['vaegtstart'];
   } 
   else 
   {
    echo $row['vaegtnu'];
   }   
   echo '"/>&nbsp;kg&nbsp;&nbsp;';

Comment: I have just added vaegtnu to: <?php if (isset($_POST['submitpraes'])){
$praesTitel = $_POST['kontypeBeskriv'];   
$konID = $_POST['konID']; 
$praesStr = $_POST['praesidag'];
$vaegtnu = $_POST['vaegtnu'];
But it didn't help..

Comment: please check my answer below.. You seem to be having problems with variables names vs your input fields names. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
$vaegtnu=$_POST['vaegtnu'];

$brugerensID= $_SESSION['brugerID'];

mysql_query("UPDATE `brugere` SET vaegtnu='$vaegtnu' WHERE brugerID='$brugerensID'");
```

And tell me if it helps.

Also check that your variables match, i.e. in `XXXX = $_POST['YYYY']` YYYY should be the name of the input, and XXXX should be the name of the variable you're using in the query.

Comment: yes it all fits, except where to write $vaegtnu=$_POST('vaegtnu');

$brugerensID= $_SESSION['brugerID']; on an UPDATE?

Comment: I can send you the file on email, if it would help?

Comment: it didn't change anything setting the () instead: UPDATE brugere SET vaegtnu='' WHERE brugerID=''

Comment: sorry () was a typo, it's still []. Just echo all your variables and check whether they are correctly set

Comment: I GOT IT!
It WAS an if isset that was missing, I wasen't sure to use it for UPDATE. But now its working Yay!
Thank you so much for taking your time to help.
Merry Christmas everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe try removing the single quotes around the `$brugerensID` if your value is an integer:

`mysql_query("UPDATE brugere SET vaegtnu='$vaegtnu' WHERE brugerID=$brugerensID");`

This depends on how your schema is set up. Are you getting any PHP warnings or error messages?

Comment: sorry! I didn't help removing the single quotes around the $brugerensID

Comment: can you help me with this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923599/a-difficult-many-to-many-relation-with-checkboxes